# Нужно ли тире перед "что"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> — Виктор начал действовать.
> — Виктор — что?

Comment: Можете раскрыть смысл вопроса?

Comment: ну, человек плохо понял фразу и переспросил/уточнил.

Comment: При паузе после слова Виктор: _Виктор – что?_ (интонационное тире). Если паузы нет, то возможен и такой вариант: _Виктор что?_

Answer (score 1):

Нужно, конечно, куда ж без него! О_о

Правило  не обнаруживается; может, под это подгоним:

[для еще большего эффекта неожиданности тире может отделять любую часть предложения](http://gramatik.ru/kogda-stavitsya-tire/).

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо оформление с цитатой, так как здесь задаётся вопрос от услышанного, дословного фрагмента. Например:
*Он сегодня пошёл в зоопарк.

"Он сегодня пошёл" — что [дальше]?* || Цитируется первый фрагмент сказанного предложения, а потом вопрос, чтоб узнать второй фрагмент. Это частая разговорная конструкция. **Тире требуется** для разграничения цитаты и вопроса к ней.

*"Виктор" — что?

"Виктор начал" — что [потом было сказано]?*
Или же с глаголом и без цитаты:
*Виктор что начал?*

Ср.:
*А Виктор что?

Виктор что там?* || В обоих случаях о Викторе речи не было.

Разница между вопросом к цитате и просто дословным повторением сказанного в вопросе:
*— Мы сегодня идём в зоопарк.

— "Мы сегодня идём" — что?* || Интонация повторения чужих слов.
или
*— Куда мы сегодня идём?* || Необходимо согласование с вопросительным словом. При обычном повторении (без цитаты) возможно переформулировать или что-то поменять местами, заменить (синонимом), пропустить. И это ни на что не влияет, в частности на понимание вопроса:
*— Мы сегодня идём в зоопарк.

— Куда мы пойдём?*
а не
*Мы пойдём — что?*
Если изменение повторяемого текста нарушает смысл и понимание, то это цитата как **неизменяемое** дословное повторение, и необходимо соответствующее оформление.

Answer (score 0):

Между «Виктор» и «что» нет никаких причин ставить какой-либо знак: здесь нет каких-либо пауз, границ синтаксических сегментов или чего-то подобного.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно: это **интонационное** тире. "Куда же без" не тире, а смены интонации - с интонации повторения чужой речи на интонацию собственного переспроса.

> Между «Виктор» и «что» нет никаких причин ставить какой-либо знак.

Есть, и выше я эту причину назвал.

А вот никакого "оформления с цитатой" не нужно, и это совершенно точно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128123/discussion-on-answer-by-------).