# Нужны ли кавычки при повторении чужих слов?

Tags: кавычки

Вариант 1:

> — Тебе нужно туда поехать!
>
> — Что значит «поехать»? Ты в своем уме?

Вариант 2:

> — Купишь билеты на автобус?
>
> — Автобус? — переспросил Олег.
>
> — Ну, у нас не хватит денег на такси.

Правильно ли использованы кавычки? Нужны ли они в первом варианте? Нужны ли во втором?

Comment: После "ну" запятая не нужна, там частица, а не междометие.

Comment: @oleedd авторский интонационный произвол))

Comment: Запятую можно, если "ну" выражает раздумье, но там частица "ну" нужна для усиления фразы.

Comment: Более сложный случай: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466955

Comment: Спасибо, гляну тему поподробнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом нужна:
*Что значит [в данном случае слово] «поехать»?

Что значит [фраза] «туда поехать»?*
Цитируется фраза либо слово.
В Нацкорпусе тоже так.

А во втором не нужна. Равносильно следующему:
*На автобус?* || Спрашивается о серьёзности, при этом выражается недовольство.
Не спрашивается о значении. Нет цитирования. Нельзя вставить "слово".

После "ну" запятая не нужна, гораздо вероятнее, что это частица, а не междометие.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Какой ещё метод можно использовать (ранее предложена подстановка "слово"/"фраза").

В первом варианте не совсем спрашивается о значении. И там и там выражается недовольство (в разной степени).

Когда цитата, нельзя никак изменить текст. Такое в первом примере.
Во втором примере сложно изменить, но реально:
*Серьёзно предлагаешь автобус?* || Смысл тот же.
*На автобус купить?*

Этот метод ключевой.

Comment: Спасибо. Принял к сведению.

Comment: Интересно то, что во втором варианте не переспрашивание (хотя очень похоже). Спрашивают о серьёзности этих слов. Переспрашивание, если так: *Какие билеты?*

Comment: Да, именно так я и думал.